# _burn() odd behaviour

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testing, openzeppelin, burn

I stumbled upon an issue with `burn()` in OpenZeppelin ERC20 contracts. I have the following test:

```
import { time, loadFixture } from "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers";
import { anyValue } from "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers/withArgs";
import { expect } from "chai";
import { ethers } from "hardhat";
import {rpcBlock} from "hardhat/internal/core/jsonrpc/types/output/block";
import {address} from "hardhat/internal/core/config/config-validation";

describe("MSGSNDR", function () {
  // We define a fixture to reuse the same setup in every test.
  // We use loadFixture to run this setup once, snapshot that state,
  // and reset Hardhat Network to that snapshot in every test.
  async function deployContractFixture() {

    // Contracts are deployed using the first signer/account by default
    const [owner, otherAccount, yetAnotherAccount] = await ethers.getSigners();

    const MSGSNDR = await ethers.getContractFactory("MSGSNDR");
    const msgsndr = await MSGSNDR.deploy("MSGSNDR", "MSGS");

    return { msgsndr, owner, otherAccount, yetAnotherAccount };
  }

  describe("Burnable", function () {

    it("burn(): burn 2_400 wei", async function () {
      const { msgsndr, owner, otherAccount } = await loadFixture(deployContractFixture);

      await msgsndr.mint(otherAccount.address, 10_000);
      await expect(msgsndr.connect(otherAccount).burn(2_400))
          .to.emit(msgsndr, 'Transfer')
          .withArgs(otherAccount.address, ethers.constants.AddressZero, 2_400);
      expect(await msgsndr.balanceOf(otherAccount.address)).to.equal(7_600);
    });
  });
});
```

I am testing behaviour of `_burn()` and found that the following two versions of the contract behave in different ways:

1. This contract **fails**. It uses `_burn()` copied verbatim from the [OpenZeppelin GitHub repo](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/d59306bd06a241083841c2e4a39db08e1f3722cc/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol).

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
import 'hardhat/console.sol';

contract MSGSNDR is ERC20, ERC20Burnable, Ownable {

    mapping(address => uint256) private _balances;
    uint256 private _totalSupply;

    constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_) ERC20(name_, symbol_) {
        _totalSupply = 10_000;
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 _amount) public {

        _mint(to, _amount);

    }

    /**
     * copied from: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/d59306bd06a241083841c2e4a39db08e1f3722cc/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol
     * @dev Destroys `amount` tokens from `account`, reducing the
     * total supply.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event with `to` set to the zero address.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `account` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `account` must have at least `amount` tokens.
     */
    function _burn(address account, uint256 amount) internal override virtual {
        require(account != address(0), "ERC20: burn from the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(account, address(0), amount);

        uint256 accountBalance = _balances[account];
        require(accountBalance >= amount, "ERC20: burn amount exceeds balance");
        unchecked {
            _balances[account] = accountBalance - amount;
            // Overflow not possible: amount <= accountBalance <= totalSupply.
            _totalSupply -= amount;
        }

        emit Transfer(account, address(0), amount);

        _afterTokenTransfer(account, address(0), amount);
    }
}
```

2. This contract **passes**.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
import 'hardhat/console.sol';

contract MSGSNDR is ERC20, ERC20Burnable, Ownable {

    mapping(address => uint256) private _balances;
    uint256 private _totalSupply;

    constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_) ERC20(name_, symbol_) {
        _totalSupply = 10_000;
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 _amount) public {

        _mint(to, _amount);

    }
}
```

What could be causing this change of behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- After a couple of xx minutes debug in Remix by the revert message is : "ERC20: burn amount exceeds balance".
- I realize that to put the _balances() and _totalSupply in your MSGSNDR, you redefined it in you contract eventhough they already **private defined** in ERC20 contract.
- That cause the problem that when the contract call _balances(account) they return to 0, but in the other side balanceOf(account) work completely fine.
- The solution is :

1. Instead of assign totalsupply directly, you can mint to owner the amount you want.
2. Instead of using _balances() using balanceOf().
3. And finally remove _balances() and _totalSupply assign lines in your code.