# How variable work when I predefined a private variable from inheritanced Contract?

Tags: solidity, state-variable, burn

- I have see a question here : [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144641/burn-odd-behaviour/144675#144675) . Where someone have some problem with ERC0 _burn(), to the point I see that He redefined 2 variable _totalSupply, _balances in his contract to use :

[image]

even though they private defined in ERC20 Contract :
[image]

- So that he cant burn any thing with revert message :

> ERC20: burn amount exceeds balance

due to in _burn, the _balances[account] result to 0, but balanceOf(account) work completely fine, even it still call to _balances[account].
[image]

- So what the problem between _balances in his contract and _balances defined in ERC0? Do they is a one or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Solidity, when you define a private variable in a contract, it cannot be accessed directly by derived contracts. This means that if you define a private variable in a parent contract and then inherit from that contract in a child contract, the child contract will not be able to access the private variable.

However, you can provide public or internal getter functions in the parent contract to allow the child contract to access the private variable indirectly. For example, you can define an internal getter function in the parent contract that returns the value of the private variable, and then call this function from the child contract.

It's important to note that if you define a private variable in a parent contract and then define a variable with the same name in a child contract, the child contract's variable will shadow the parent contract's variable, and the child contract will not be able to access the parent contract's variable.

```
// Parent contract
contract Parent {
 uint private myPrivateVar;

 // Internal getter function to allow access to private variable
 function getMyPrivateVar() internal view returns (uint) {
     return myPrivateVar;
 }
}

// Child contract
contract Child is Parent {
 function doSomething() external {
     uint myVar = getMyPrivateVar();
     // Do something with myVar
 }
}
```